# how to use hyperlink in JQuery in one column of a table

Tags: jquery, mdbootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_btn").click(function() {
    var _empID = document.getElementById('search').value;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'coinsIndentsServlet?empid=' + _empID,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 2500,
      "columns": [{
        "data": "INDENTNO",
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return '<a href="Test.html' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
        }
      }],
      success: function(response) {
        $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', response.indents);
        $('#tabledata').bootstrapTable('load', response.egps);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

how to hyperlink one column in mdbootstrap using jquery .
here iam using this above code but iam not getting the hyperlink .
i need only one column to be hyperlinked.

Answer (score 0):

You should change a little thing:

```
      return '<a href="Test.html' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
```

to

```
      return '<a href="Test.html?test_id=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
```

### Output:

if data = "1":

```
<a href='Test.html?test_id=1'>1</a>
```

you should find a better title for the link

Comment: but also i am not getting that hyperlink

Comment: can you tell me what you get?  are you sure your program execute this line? you can add console.log or `alert` to make sure this line is executed

Comment: I have posted one question can you go through it?

Comment: can u help me out